# Obtain an HWND on a window which does not belong to the created subprocess

Tags: c++, winapi, explorer, hwnd

I'm launching a new Windows Explorer window with the following code and need to obtain a HWND of the window, preferably as early as possible (i.e. before the window is shown):

```
char cmdLine[MAX_PATH] = "explorer.exe";
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

CreateProcess(
 NULL,
 cmdLine,
 NULL,
 NULL,
 FALSE,
 0,
 NULL,
 NULL,
 &si,
 &pi
);
```

However, the window doesn't belong to the created subprocess, so obtaining a handle requires unconventional tricks. What I tried so far is to open the window to a directory with a special name (like `%TEMP%\<guid>`) and to continuously scan the top-level windows till one whose title contains the directory's path is found. This is clearly suboptimal so I'm searching for some know-how on how to do this "properly". Perhaps the Explorer infrastructure features way to do this cleanly. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use the [ShellWindows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393) object to enumerate Explorer windows.

Comment: An [event hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640\(v=vs.85\).aspx) can capture window creation.

Comment: if you want open some folder view - simply call `ShellExecuteExW` with `SEE_MASK_IDLIST` and `lpIDList = ILCreateFromPath(path)`. anyway you not need `HWND` - you ask about your (wrong) solution implementation instead of your real target

Comment: You didn't explain your main goal. What do you want to do after you obtain explorer's `HWND`?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks, Jonathan! This helps me with my hack, somewhat, but since posting this, I found out about IExplorerBrowser and CLSID_ExplorerBrowser which allow me to (at least partially) achieve my goal: to embed an explorer window in another window. This also answers Barmak's question. I want to embed a full browser window (without the frame) and once I locate the HWND, it works great, but the question is how to obtain it before it becomes visible to the user and how to be sure the right one is found.

Comment: @RbMm I absolutely need a HWND.

Comment: for what you need some (what ?) `HWND` ?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. If you want to host an instance of Explorer you need to implement the `IShellBrowser` interface.

Comment: Agree that this sounds like an XY problem. Use the `IExplorerBrowser` interface to embed Explorer inside your window.